# BigQuery Standard SQL: How to get median of difference between two columns?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How can I get the median difference after subtracting two columns in a table after I set the dialect to `Standard SQL`?

These are the things that I have tried and failed with:

```
SELECT
  symbol,
  median(max_height-min_height)
FROM
  `body_table-1345.bodies.heights`
WHERE
  symbol = 'mouse_1344'
  AND max_height> 0
  AND min_height> 0
  AND (measure_date> '2017-11-01 08:45:00.000 UTC'
    AND measure_date< '2017-11-30 17:00:00.000 UTC')
GROUP BY
  symbol
```

but I get the error `Error: Function not found: median at [3:3]`

The following works with `Legacy SQL` but not with `Standard SQL`:

```
SELECT
  symbol,
  NTH(501, QUANTILES(max_height-min_height, 1001))
FROM
  `body_table-1345.bodies.heights`
WHERE
  symbol = 'mouse_1344'
  AND max_height> 0
  AND min_height> 0
  AND (measure_date> '2017-11-01 08:45:00.000 UTC'
    AND measure_date< '2017-11-30 17:00:00.000 UTC')
GROUP BY
  symbol
```

The columns I'd like to subtract are `max_height` and `min_height`.

Answer (score 4):

Instead, you can use a slight variation of ANSI standard percentile functions.

```
SELECT DISTINCT symbol,
       percentile_cont(max_height-min_height, 0.5) over (partition by symbol )
FROM `body_table-1345.bodies.heights`
WHERE symbol = 'mouse_1344' AND
      max_height > 0 AND
      min_height > 0 AND
      (measure_date> '2017-11-01 08:45:00.000 UTC' AND
       measure_date< '2017-11-30 17:00:00.000 UTC'
      );
```

Unfortunately, this is one of the analytic functions that is only available as an analytic function and not as an aggregation function.  Hence, the `SELECT DISTINCT` syntax rather than `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I just implemented your code and it worked. From what I am learning from you answer, is it true that it is a requirement to first specify “DISTINCT symbol) before using that in OVER() clause?

Comment: @Arsik36 . . . Not at all.  The purpose here is the `percentile_cont()` is a window function, not an aggregation function, so the `select distinct` essentially acts like a `group by` in this case.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you for you explanation, I voted your answer up. Thank you for sharing your knowledge